# Widgets de cabeça para baixo em Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Estou com um problema ao executar qualquer tela Kivy, pois ela sempre aparece de cabeça para baixo. Este problema é apenas com essa especifica biblioteca, as demais que utilizo funcionam normalmente.

Um simples código como:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
         return Label( text = 'Hello World' )

TestApp().run()
```

Resulta numa tela de cabeça para baixo, como nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar F1 para às configurações, e tem o arquivo de configuração também.

O ítem "Rotation" deve estar em 0. Provavelmente está em 180 no seu caso:

[image: Tela de settings da Kivy]

Módulo:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.settings.html

Arquivo:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/config.html#configure-kivy

Comment: Eu não consegui abrir essa janela que você me apontou. A tecla de atalho F1 abre as configurações do Pycharm e não do Kivy. Teria como ensinar a abrir essa tela de configurações, por favor @bacco

Comment: F1 na sua aplicação, não na IDE De qualquer forma, tem o arquivo de config tambem: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/config.html#configure-kivy

Comment: Muito obrigado, com esse ultimo link agora consegui finalmente ><

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com esse link tambem